# Distributive arrows in xypic

Tags: arrows, xy-pic

I am trying to draw "distributive arrows" in `xypic`, but I can't make it look nice.  Here is a MWE:

```
\xymatrix{a\ar @/^1.4pc/[r]  \ar @/^1.4pc/[rrr]  &( b &+& c)}
```

Does anyone know how to do this well?

Comment: Hi Andrew, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I indented your code using `{}`, and removed the thanks- it seems strange, but it helps to keep the site more 'Question & Answer' oriented. Could you turn your snippet into a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)? It really helps folks who want to help.

Comment: Using another package instead of `xy` would be an option for you?

Comment: I would be open to using another package, if I could get it to work well.

Comment: What do you mean by "well"? Matsaya has already provided an answer; is it something like that what you want or do you want anything different?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little modification of your code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@C=0.5cm{a\ar @/^1pc/[rr]  \ar @/^2pc/[rrrr]  &&( b &+& c)}
\end{document}
```

I put one extra column between a and b, change the curving of the first arrow and the size of the column entries (with `@C=0.5cm`).

But I prefer another way to place the `+`: use an empty arrow, like that

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{a\ar @/^1pc/[r]  \ar @/^2pc/[rr]  &( b\ar@{}[r]|{+} & c)}
\end{document}
```

The results is more or less the same, but the code is less cumbersome.

And the results :

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  That looks a lot better than what I originally had.